# How do I log a users ISP hostname

Tags: php, ip

I currently have a website which has different packages the user can buy, however, I don’t want the user to be passing their membership around for free therefore I would like to implement something which would not allow them from doing this such as an IP lock, or am ISP lock or someone suggested, lock it to the first computer/laptop they logon to and the first phone they logon to so they can use both with anyone else trying to login just getting outputted an error message letting them know they can’t. I’m preferably looking to implement something along those lines in PHP.

Does anyone have any ideas or recommendations?
Thanks

Comment: So you want to punish legitimate users so that you can try and catch abusers? If you implement a system in which only one concurrent session is allowed per user then that could be the most sane solution.

Comment: Lock on IP seems crazy. If you login with your phone, you can get different IP's every time. People are often using different WiFi (with different ISP's like home, work, a friends place etc.)

Comment: if i have an account with you I wouldn't stay long because i couldn't use any other device other than my first signup device this is a crazy way to limit use of your product i would explore other methods.  Believe me this idea will not catch on to easily.

Comment: You might get a number of users using the same IP address by virtual their route to the internet, i.e via an office network.  You might consider reverse geocoding the IP address and then log the geographic region in which each login occurs - if the users moves around too frequently, you might consider it abuse.  If you track the user agent (browser) you might be able to use that too to give more intelligence to whether a given ID is being abused.  I'd be careful to ensure you have a mechanism to let the user unblock easily, as anything you devise will have legitimate situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all those from the following code:

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url=file_get_contents("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ip");
preg_match_all('/<th>(.*?)<\/th><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$url,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);
$isp=$output[1][2];
$city=$output[9][2];
$state=$output[8][2];
$zipcode=$output[12][2];
$country=$output[7][2];
?>
```